# For a well orderable, infinite cardinal number $\kappa$, $\kappa + 1 =_c \kappa$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Here is my attempt at the proof:

Clearly $\kappa \leq_c \kappa + 1$. It suffices to show that $\kappa + 1 \leq_c \kappa$. By definition, $$\kappa + 1 := \kappa \uplus \{0\} := (\{\flat\} \times \kappa) \cup (\{\flat\flat\} \times \ \{0\}).$$ Where $\flat = \emptyset$ and $\flat\flat = \{\emptyset\}$.

Define $\varphi: \kappa +1 \rightarrow \kappa$ by $$
\varphi(a,b) = \left\{
        \begin{array}{ll}
            0 & \quad (a,b) = (\flat\flat,0) \\
            \omega_0 & \quad (a,b) = (\flat,0) \\
            \omega_{i+1} & \quad (a,b) = (\flat,\omega_i) \\
            \omega & \quad (a,b) = (\flat,\omega_N) \\
            S(x) & \quad (a,b) = (\flat,x)
        \end{array}
    \right.
.$$

Where

1) $0$ is the minimal element in $\kappa$,

2) $\omega_i$ is the $i$th limit point in $\kappa$,

3) $\omega$ is the "last" general point in $\kappa$ ( $\forall x \in \kappa$ $\omega < S(x)$ ),

4) $\omega_N$ is the "last" limit point in $\kappa$ ($N \in \mathbb{N}$),

5) $x$ is neither a limit point nor the minimal element $0$.

$\varphi$ is well defined as $\kappa$ is well ordered. By inspection, $\varphi$ is injective and hence, by definition, $\kappa + 1 \leq_c \kappa$. Apply Shr$\ddot{o}$der-Bernstien.

This completes the proof $\Diamond$?

(Essentially, I attempted to "shift" $\kappa$ and started at a new point, but as $\kappa$ is infinite, there is no effect. I suppose I tried to formalize the "Infinite Hotel" argument.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the usual definition: $\kappa+1=\kappa\cup\{\kappa\}$ you can write
$$f:\kappa+1\longrightarrow\kappa$$
as

$$f(\kappa)=0;$$
$$f(n)=n+1\qquad\hbox{for $n$ finite};$$
$$f(\alpha)=\alpha\qquad\hbox{otherwise}.$$
Is cleaner.

Comment: That is much cleaner. Unfortunately, I don't believe the textbook I'm using (_Notes on Set Theory_ by Moschovakis) has introduce that  "usual" definition. :/ Needless to say, I don't particularly care for the book.

Comment: I think the you can "translate" to your definition. Specifically, shifting the finite cardinals for "make room" for the new element is all you need. And why a new sign for $\emptyset$?